# django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed on unit tests with postgres

Tags: python, django, pytest

My unit tests are working perfectly on sqlite but I'm trying to make them work on postgres. I'm using python 3.6 and Django 2.2.28.

Unit test fails when Django tries to auth the user:

```
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/response.py:169: in set_cookie
    self.cookies[key] = value
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/cookies.py:518: in __setitem__
    if isinstance(value, Morsel):
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py:256: in inner
    self._setup()
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py:392: in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py:24: in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py:12: in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py:189: in get_user
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py:102: in get_user
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py:82: in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:402: in get
    num = len(clone)
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:256: in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1242: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:55: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1140: in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:256: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:235: in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:89: in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:235: in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fd3e015f710>, name = None

    def create_cursor(self, name=None):
        if name:
            # In autocommit mode, the cursor will be used outside of a
            # transaction, hence use a holdable cursor.
            cursor = self.connection.cursor(name, scrollable=False, withhold=self.connection.autocommit)
        else:
>           cursor = self.connection.cursor()
E           django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed

.tox/commonenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:223: InterfaceError
```

My deps are:

```
deps = pip == 20.2.4
       setuptools == 45.1.0
       pytest == 6.1.2
       pytest-django == 4.4.0
       faker == 5.0.0
       factory_boy == 2.12.0
       pytest-factoryboy == 2.0.3
       pytest-cov == 2.8.1
       pytest-xdist == 1.34.0
       pylint == 2.4.2
       pylint-django == 2.0.11
       pylint-celery == 0.3
```

My unit test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.small
@pytest.mark.parametrize("url", [
    "/site-url/preview/{}/",
    "/console/sites/{0}/pages/{1}"
])
def test_renders_userid(admin_client, content_version_factory, url):
    version = content_version_factory()
    if "{1}" in url:
        url = url.format(version.page.site.pk, version.page.pk)
    else:
        url = url.format(version.uuid)
    assert admin_client.cookies.get("userId") is None
    response = admin_client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    response_user_id = response.cookies.get("userId")
    assert response_user_id is not None
    assert response_user_id.value == "admin"
    admin_user_id = admin_client.cookies.get("userId")
    assert admin_user_id is not None
    assert admin_user_id.value == "admin"
    admin_client.cookies["userId"] = "some.user"
    response = admin_client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    response_user_id = response.cookies.get("userId")
    assert response_user_id is None
    assert admin_user_id is not None
    assert admin_user_id.value == "some.user"
    admin_client.logout()
    assert admin_client.cookies.get("userId") is None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my failling tests were fixed after I added

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
```